# How do I redirect command completion output?

Tags: bash, io-redirection, pipe, autocomplete

On the command line, I can redirect or pipe output of a command to a file or another command using the `>` or `|` operator after the command. I have come across a less standard situation that I would like to redirect the output to a file, but I don't seem to have the oppurtunity to redirect it:

When at a new terminal,

```
[chiliNUT ~]$
```

if I press <kbd>Tab</kbd> without typing anything first, I get asked

```
display all 1725 possibilities? (y or n)
```

and if I then type <kbd>y</kbd>, I get a nice long list of different commands. How can I redirect or pipe this output to a file? I don't seem to get the chance to type `> myfile.txt` anywhere.

Using *CentOS release 6.4 (Final)*.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could make use of the builtin `compgen`:

```
compgen: compgen [-abcdefgjksuv] [-o option]  [-A action] [-G globpat]
[-W wordlist]  [-F function] [-C command] [-X filterpat] [-P prefix]
[-S suffix] [word]

    Display possible completions depending on the options.

    Intended to be used from within a shell function generating possible
    completions.  If the optional WORD argument is supplied, matches against
    WORD are generated.

    Exit Status:
    Returns success unless an invalid option is supplied or an error occurs.
```

<kbd>TAB</kbd> at the prompt would list commands, shell builtins, keywords, aliases and functions.  So you could say:

```
compgen -cbka -A function | grep '^y' > myfile.txt
```

to get all the options that you see upon typing <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd> at the shell prompt into the file `myfile.txt`.

Eliminate the `grep` pipeline in order to get all the possible commands, functions, ... into the file:

```
compgen -cbka -A function > myfile.txt
```

Comment: Awesome! You're answer as written actually only grabs the commands / files that start with the letter y, so just `compgen -cbka -A function > myfile.txt` grabs the full output. Thanks! I (obviously) never knew about this new interesting function.

Comment: Oh, that's clever.

Comment: @chiliNUT I did mention that the command would get those starting with `y` :)  This was pretty much in line with what you showed in the question!

Comment: Oh, ha, misunderstood a little. The 'y' in my question actually corresponds to 'yes' vs 'no'; I enter 'y' and it spits out all those commands, I enter 'n' and it doesn't output anything.

Comment: @chiliNUT I've updated the answer to reflect that as well.

Comment: Great answer, but I found that the pipe to `grep` is unnecessary.  `compgen -cbka -A function 'y' > myfile.txt` produces the same results on my machine.