# Bash: redirect command argument completion

Tags: bash, shell, autocomplete

When you have written in the shell `$ somecmd` and double tab, you get all the suggestions that apply for that command. How can you redirect this output?

I am aware of [compgen](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html), it seems to be able to do what I want, but I can only make it print possible completions for the command name, but not for the command arguments.

Edit:

Just to clarify. As I mentioned above, I know how to get the list of all possible command name completions as is described in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127506/how-do-i-redirect-command-completion-output). The question here is how to get the completion list for an argument?

If you have in shell `$ somecmd` and then double-hit tab, it will show for example `a`, `ab`, `abc`.\

If you have in shell `$ somecmd ab`, double-tabbing returns `ab` and `abc`.

Comment: Which shell are you using?

Comment: It is bash, I will fix the question.

Comment: If you're just trying to get a list of the available options, there is often `--help`, or even the man page.

Comment: @roaima, you know how if you're in a directory with two PDF files and a bunch of source code or something, you can type `evince <TAB><TAB>` and only the PDF file names come up as suggested autocompletes?  I think that's what OP is looking for when he says "possible completions... for the command arguments."

Comment: I saw this question, but it is about completion of the command name, but not the arguments of a command.

Comment: The first sentence suggests you're looking for a list of the argument names. The second refers to the argument values. Your question might benefit from [a little update](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/230054/edit) to clarify this, perhaps.

Comment: @user1717828 to me, a command is something like your `evince`. A command argument would be something like `-display` and the argument value would be something like `:0`. What is still not clear to me is what it is that the OP actually wants command completion for.

Comment: @roaima, My guess is `evince FILE1.pdf`, where `FILE1.pdf` is the command argument. He wants the list `FILE1.pdf FILE2.pdf FILE3.pdf` as his "command argument" list. I could be wrong though.  Sogartar, could you clarify your question?

Comment: @Sogartar That question is about anything bash can complete, including command names and arguments.

Comment: @user1717828 Yes that is correct. I want the list of possible arguments that I can supply on the place of the argument argument.

Comment: @Sogartar take a look at the files in `/etc/bash_completions.d/` On my system the `openvpn` completion function works as you require, listing not only command arguments but also the set of possible files for those arguments.